# Is it possible to parameterise a lambda in Linq to Entities Select

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

I have 2 entity framework queries that are almost identical apart the lambda for 2 properties; Location and DateTime in the `Select()` method.

```
var departQuery = _dataContext
    .Job                
    .Where(j => j.Departure.DateTime >= startDate && j.Departure.DateTime <= endDate)
    .Select(j => new DispatchDashboardItem()
    {
        JobId = j.Id,
        Direction = "PickUp",
        CustomerName = j.Driver.Name,
        Vehicle = j.Vehicle,
        Location = j.Departure.MeetingLocation.Name,
        DateTime = j.Departure.DateTime,
    });

var returnQuery = _dataContext
    .Job                
    .Where(j => j.Return.DateTime >= startDate && j.Return.DateTime <= endDate)
    .Select(j => new DispatchDashboardItem()
    {
        JobId = j.Id,
        Direction = "DropOff",
        CustomerName = j.Driver.Name,
        Vehicle = j.Vehicle,
        Location = j.Return.MeetingLocation.Name,
        DateTime = j.Return.DateTime,
    });
```

I have tried creating an extension method to share the select which works without the func param, but which throws an exception then I use the location param:

```
    public static IQueryable<DashboardItem> SelectDashboardItem(this IQueryable<Job> query, 
            string direction, 
            Func<Job, MeetingDetail> location)
    {
        return query
            .Select(j => new DashboardItem()
            {
                JobId = j.Id,
                Direction = direction,
                CustomerName = j.Driver.Name,
                Vehicle = j.Vehicle,
                // This works without using the func
                Location = location(j).MeetingLocation.Name,
                DateTime = location(j).DateTime,                    
            });
    }
```

I see his error message:

> The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this syntax with the let statement to achieve the composition in one swoop. You would need a base class, or better an interface, for the commonality between your Departure and Return entities.

```
var query = from job in _dataContext.Job
    let departureOrReturn = (direction == "PickUp" ? job.Departure : job.Return) as BaseReturnOrDeparture
    where (departureOrReturn.DateTime >= startDate && departureOrReturn.DateTime <= endDate)
    select new DispatchDashboardItem
    {
        JobId = job.Id,
        Direction = direction,
        CustomerName = job.Driver.Name,
        Vehicle = job.Vehicle,
        Location = deptartureOrReturn.MeetingLocation.Name,
        DateTime = deptartureOrReturn.DateTime,
    };
```

Comment: Sorry maybe my lengthy question has caused confusion is in the .Select method, `Location` and `DateTime` that needs to use either `j.Return` or `j.Departure` depending on the direction. Hence my trying to move it to an extension method.

Comment: Check the last edit and the second syntax. I don't have a compiler handy but something like that is an easier way to accomplish this.

Comment: no idea about the downvote. Your solution in the method syntax query
`.Select(job => new {deptOrReturn = direction == "Pick up" ? job.Departure : job.Return, job})
.Select(j => new DispatchDashboardItem()
                {
                    JobId = j.job.Id,                   
                    Location = j.deptOrReturn.MeetingLocation.Name                   
                    });`

Comment: Sorry, not in front of the compiler. Are you stating there's a syntax issue I should fix?

Comment: no just posted the equivalent solution using the `method syntax` as thats what I'm using. Which is what `let` resolves to anyway.

Comment: Ah gotcha, too bad SO comments don't allow for code syntax, see it now ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of use `Func` as parameter use an `Expression`.Pass the same lambda expression you are using as parameter, it will implicitly converted. Now to achieve what you need you will need to use [LinqKit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit/) library :

```
public static IQueryable<DashboardItem> SelectDashboardItem(this IQueryable<Job> query, 
            string direction, 
            Expression<Func<Job, MeetingDetail>> location)
    {
      return query.AsExpandable()
        .Select(j => new DashboardItem()
        {
            JobId = j.Id,
            Direction = direction,
            CustomerName = j.Driver.Name,
            Vehicle = j.Vehicle,
            // This works without using the func
            Location = location.Invoke(j).MeetingLocation.Name,
            DateTime = location.Invoke(j).DateTime,                    
        });
    }
```

[**Explanation:**](http://tomasp.net/blog/linq-expand.aspx/)

`ToExpandable` creates a thin wrapper around the [DLINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library) Table object. Thanks to this wrapper you can use second method called `Invoke` that extends the `Expression` class to invoke the lambda expression while making it still possible to translate query to T-SQL. This works because when converting to the expression tree, the wrapper replaces all occurrences of `Invoke` method by expression trees of the invoked lambda expression and passes these expressions to DLINQ that is able to translate the expanded query to T-SQL.

Comment: So how to I use the param? `location(j).MeetingLocation.Name` or `location.MeetingLocation.Name` is not valid

Comment: Invoke() returns a System.Linq.Expressions.Expression not the object from the func

Comment: No, that is an extension method to `Expression` class from Linqkit library, Did you install it?

Comment: Cannot check this for correctness atm, I forgot this .sln is still on EF 4.3 :( Will have to review once I've upgrade.

Comment: I down-voted this because for such a simple linq-ready task, you've suggested an Expression extension method, requiring a dynamic linq package being installed.

Comment: To be fair I started the idea as my extension method was using a `func<>`